# Problem with datagridview: unexpected exception

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, datagridview

I have 1 MDI Parent form named as `MainForm` and 2 child forms WorkForm and `UserOp`.

`WorkForm` has `datagridview` that displays the `users` and its `datasource` is `BindingList`.the `BindingList` is created from a `List` of `type user` and list is declared in parent and is accessed in this with refrence i.e if i make any change to this list eventually it changes the list at parent. here is code how it is done.

```
 MainForm mainForm;
 public WorkForm(MainForm main)
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            this.mainForm = main;
}
```

similarly it is accessed from `UserOp`.now if i delete user from the list and WorkForm is already open then datagrid view gives default error that means i have to handle the `DataError` Event.I again update the `BindingList` and again assign it to `datagrid datasource`.

this resolves the issue of error but after that exception is now shown sometimes not all times in `program.cs`
 this happens when after deleting I just take mouse over the form while it is inactive if form gets clicked then no exception.
which reads`Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: e.RowIndex`
at line  `Application.Run(new MainForm());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some times the `RowIndex` can be -1 or even equal to `Count/Length` of the collection  in the events.

You should check for that :)